# Работа с массивами на php

Tags: php

Проблема такова:

не могу работать со значениями массива

в основном файле есть запись

```
    include('Node.inc');
    $obj = new Node();
    $obj->set();
    echo '< p>---------------Weight-------------< p>';
    $obj->get();
```

файл Node.inc

```
class Node{
    private $mas = array();
function set(){
    global $mas;
    $mas[] = 1;
    //print_r($mas);
}
function get(){print_r($mas);}

}
```

При вызове функции set() из основного файла значения естественно видны, а в фунции get() - нет. Как так сделать чтобы было видно не вставляя return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Node{
  private $mas = array();

  function set(){
      $this->mas[] = 1;
      //print_r($mas);
  }
  function get(){
    print_r($this->mas);
  }
}
```

Думаю вам как то так нужно сделать

Comment: да. работает.

Answer (score 3):

У вас поле в классе объявлено:

```
private $mas = array();
```

Но вы почему-то его не используете:

```
function set() {
    $this->mas[] = 1;
    print_r($this->mas);
}
function get(){
    print_r($this->mas);
}
```